# Is it possible to have a cancellation token source that cancels only some waiters?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, cancellation, cancellationtokensource

Given:

- `BlockingCollection<T> coll`
- `CancellationTokenSource cts`
- 10 threads blocked on `coll.GetConsumingEnumerable(cts.Token)`

So `cts.Cancel()` cancels all the 10 threads.

Is it possible to write a custom cancellation token source which can be told to cancel only some of the threads? So:

```
cts.Cancel(5)
```

would cancel only 5 of the blocked threads. Any 5.

?

Answer (score 3):

No.  You'll need to have multiple different cancellation tokens instead, have each of the consumers using their own token, and cancel some number of the collection of tokens.

That said you could encapsulate much of this behavior by creating a cancellation token collection of some sort that has a method to generate a new token and another to cancel some number of the tokens it's given out.